# 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception'.. it couldn't find MainWindow, which no longer exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I deleted all my .xib files a while ago, and recently changed my identifier. Now its started giving me this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
>   'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name
>   'MainWindow''

MainWindow was deleted a while ago, and removing MainWindow from deployment info means that I'm just given a black screen. This is the code i have in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Am i missing something? I presume i should remove MainWindow but as i say, this is just giving me a black screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because the `NSMainNibFile` value is set in your `Info.plist`. It tells the OS to open that `NIB` file at launch. Since you're doing away with `NIB`s for some reason, you will have to fill in the holes that you've created by deleting the `NIB` file.

1. You've to delete the key from the `Info.plist`.
2. You have to make some changes in your `main.m`. Usually the `MainWindow.xib` contained the information about your application delegate but now you need to provide it. Find the line that reads `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` and replace it with `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"yourDelegateClassName");`
3. What you've done so far will instantiate the application delegate and your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will get called but your `window` isn't set yet as it was taken care of by the `NIB` file again. This will apply to all your outlets. Not only your `window.

You will have to make some additions to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method like this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Instantiate Window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Instantiate Root view controller
    RootViewController * viewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Instantiate navigation controller
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The above method is just a template and must be modified to your requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately this still launches with just a black screen with a navigaiton bar at the top. My RootViewController would be HomeView (the first view to be seen), correct? And where you put 'yourDelegateClassName' i also put HomeView. Is this correct? This is what i have.

Comment: yourDelegateClassName should be your application delegate, not your view controller.