# Basic View Switch Code Crashes iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I've been trying to switch two views from two separate view controllers for a while and it never works, the simulator always crashes to the home screen. I'm using Xcode 3.2.5 and this is my code -

**SwitchViewsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SwitchViewsViewController : UIViewController {
}
-(IBAction)pushButton;
@end
```

**SwitchViewsViewController.m**

```
#import "SwitchViewsViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SwitchViewsViewController

-(IBAction)pushButton {
    SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil    
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES]
    [screen release];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
}
-(IBAction)pushBack;
@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

-(IBAction)pushBack{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In interface builder, all i've done is linked the file's owner classes and the buttons. Also made the SwitchViewsViewController load first, and not MainWindow. Everything builds but when I try to run the app it crashes and sends it to the home screen. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you alloc your secondViewController you init with nib name nil, this should actually be the name of your nib file.

SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:**nil** bundle:nil];

Also, you should close your brackets ;-)

Comment: Wait, does the app crash when you press the button, or when it launches?

Comment: Crashed on the button but I fixed it, view wasn't linked to files owner

Answer (score 0):

XIB errors are rarely uncovered at compile time. So when you say you made `SwitchViewsViewController` the starting point of the app, I am assuming that you have altered the main nib file in `Info.plist`. Usually that nib file is responsible for providing information about the application delegate. So it's a pretty bad idea if you've changed it to `SwitchViewsViewController`. I suggest you incorporate the `MainWindow.xib` back. This is easier I think but if you are interested in doing programmatically than take a look at [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386019/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-it-couldnt-find-mainwindow-which/6386249#6386249).

Comment: I fixed it, the view wasn't on the secondviewcontroller wasn't linked to the files owner. Thanks for your help!